# kdb/q - geting an expression by location to its containing source code string?

Tags: kdb

I'm playing around with Q's new .Q.trp, and the debug object which you're given in case of an error.
From what I see, the debug object contains a string representation of the source code where the error occured, as well as the offset in that string where the error was triggered.

For example,

```
{
  something: 123;
  x: 123; ThisThrowsAnError[456;789]; y: 123;
}[]
```

when executing above code, the debug object would contain this code in its entirity, as well as the offset pointing to (the beginning of) ThisThrowsAnError[].

My question is - based on this information, how can I extract the entire statement that cuased the error?
For example, in above example, I'd like to extract "ThisThorwsAnError[456;789]".

Things I've thought of so far...

- Extract string from the offset, until the end of line. Doesn't work though, as there might be other statements in the same line (e.g. the "y: 123" above)
- Parse the source code (literally, with "parse"). But then what..? The output could be anything (e.g. a lambda or a statement list), and then whatever it is still needs to be mapped back to the source locations somehow

Appreciate any ideas! Thanks

Comment: Haven't need to solve this, but I would scan the function definition counting depth of various bracket structures (e.g. `{[(`, then look for the first `;` to the right of the offset at the same nesting level).

Comment: @pamphlet Thanks - didn't see a very easy way for this as you'd also need to handle those symbols occuring in strings etc., but looks like it'd probably still be the best approach indeed. I tried parsing the byte code of the function, but ran into cases where this was too complicated to handle with reasonable effort

Comment: Yep. Plus escaped quotes within strings, anything in comments...it's non-trivial. Some of the projects [here](https://code.kx.com/v2/github/) might be helpful. In particular, the various profilers may have some good parsing ideas.